# Method parameter annotated with @FormParam is always null in JAX-RS

Tags: jax-rs

I am trying to send multiple form parameters to my REST servive using `POST`. But the parameters sent by the client are always received as `null`.

```java
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public LoginData userLogin(@FormParam("picture") String picture, 
                           @FormParam("name") String name, 
                           @FormParam("email") String email) {
    ...
}
```

When I remove all the parameters like the code below, it works properly:

```java
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public LoginData userLogin() {
    ...
}
```

I've checked and the values sent by the client are not `null`.

Is there a different way to receive the parameters?

Comment: What's your `picture` parameter? Is it really a `String`?

Comment: Yes all of them are strings @CássioMazzochiMolin

Comment: How are you performing the request?

Comment: Using Postman I'm sending out a 'form-data' typed content. I debugged and found that the request gets to the method but all the parameters are null @CássioMazzochiMolin

Comment: It should work fine. Just wondering if you are using the `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)` annotation.

Comment: No I am not. Should I be using that? @CássioMazzochiMolin

Comment: Yeah, try that annotation and ensure the `Content-Type` of your `POST` request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin No brother, when I use that I get a **415: Unsupported Media Type** HTTP Error

Comment: Ensure the `Content-Type` of the request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Have a look here: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate your method with `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)`:

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Produces(MediaType.JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public LoginData userLogin(@FormParam("picture") String picture, 
                           @FormParam("name") String name, 
                           @FormParam("email") String email) {

    ...
}
```

And ensure the `Content-Type` of the request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: You were right! I added application/x-www-form-urlencoded as the content type and boom! Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be useful for the actual question. Might be useful for some people who has similar issue along with consumes annotation.

I had the similar issue even if I have the annotation it was null.
The reason was like my project was using both org.codehaus.jackson library and com.fasterxml.jackson libraries. So, mapping had issues.

Once I updated the parent and related child projects to fasterxml, the formparam annotation was working fine.

So search your project and update all the references in pom.xml and java imports from org.codehaus to com.fasterxml. FormParam and HeaderParam null issue will be resolved.